# Downgrade Hbase version

Tags: hbase, cloudera

I am currently using cloudera manager with hbase version 0.98 installed. I'd like to use version 0.94 instead. Is there any chance to downgrade from 0.98 to 0.94 and how could I do it? Any ideas?